# Using Lodash to GroupBy a specific value in another object

Tags: lodash

Using Lodash 4.17.11, how do you use `groupBy` to group by value? Let me explain:

An array of objects:

```
{
  a: 88,
  b: 11,
},
{
  a: 99,
  b: 88
},
{
  a: 22,
  b: 10
}
```

Expected result:

```
88: [{
  a: 88,
  b: 11
},
{
  a: 99,
  b: 88
}]
```

Doing the below would be based on the actual `key`

```
._groupBy(array, (arr) => arr.a)
```

But I need to group by the actual value. Am I making sense? If `b` is the same as `a` in another object, then group it.

Im working with an old code base where things are not structured. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in relatively concise manner with **ES6** and [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const group = arr => arr.reduce((r,{a,b}) => {
  if(!r[a] && !r[b]) r[a] = r[b] = {a,b}
  else {
   if(r[a]) r.grp[a] = [...r.grp[a] || [r[a]], {a,b}]
   if(r[b]) r.grp[b] = [...r.grp[b] || [r[b]], {a,b}]
  }
  return r
}, {grp: {}}).grp

console.log(group([{ a: 88, b: 11, }, { a: 99, b: 88 }, { a: 22, b: 10 }]))
console.log(group([{ a: 88, b: 11, }, { a: 99, b: 88 }, { a: 22, b: 10 }, { a: 22, b: 88 }]))
```

I would also argue that this should be considerably faster than doing 1 `groupBy` on `'a'`, then another on `'b'` and then yet another loop to `_.mergeBy` as with `lodash`.

But if you want **lodash** you could do something like this:

```js
const group = arr => {
  return _.pickBy(
    _.mergeWith(
      _.groupBy(arr, 'a'),
      _.groupBy(arr, 'b'),
     (ov,sv,k,o,s) => o[k] && s[k] ? o[k].concat(s[k]) : false
   ),
   x => _.isArray(x) && x.length > 1)
}

console.log(group([{ a: 88, b: 11, }, { a: 99, b: 88 }, { a: 22, b: 10 }]))
console.log(group([{ a: 88, b: 11, }, { a: 99, b: 88 }, { a: 22, b: 10 }, { a: 22, b: 88 }]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Where you would group by each of the props then merge only those arrays where there is the same `key` and then since the output is in `arrays` just `pickBy` the ones that have `more than 1 item` in them.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to group by each value you care about, then merge everything together.

```
_.merge(
  _.groupBy(array, (arr) => arr.a),
  _.groupBy(array, (arr) => arr.b)
)
```

It might be a bit more complex if you have nested objects; then I'd suggest just writing a custom merge function.

Comment: Thanks. Though Im not getting the expected result with that.

Comment: I've made a slight mistake with the expected result. Ive corrected.